# how to run Java project using local database(mysql) on other computers

Tags: java, php, mysql

I have a java project which connect to mysql. "url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/ap_ugc".
I need to access the database ap_ugc and get data from the already existed tables.
How could I run this project on other computer which doesn't have that database.

Answer (score 0):

Expose the database and use it's ip address.